# trigger an eventhandler on postback c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback, html-select

I am pretty new to c# programming.
I have an issue that follows:
I have a GridView on a web form, a DropDownList and a Label control. When i select a value from a DDL a Grid View is populated with rows from the database that equal the DDL condition(in my case DDL represent Countries, GV lists the Cities).
When i delete the last City from a GV using a built in GV Delete function i would like to automatically write in a Label that there are no more Cities in selected Country. 
How can i achieve that?
I tried to put

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted1(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        LabelGrid.Text = "No more cities.";
    }
}
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I could maybe also call a DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged() to be called after a deletion so it reloads a GridView, and if it is empty to write the message in Label control, but i also don't know how to do that. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using PreRender event, when that event runs the Row.Count property contains the correct value. (decremented after delete)

```
    protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            LabelGrid.Text = "No more cities.";
        }
    }
```